# React.createRef() on TextInput no working in React Native 16.3.1

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have an Textinput and I would like to set the cursor when it's not filled.

```
class SignupScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fieldOne = React.createRef(); 
    this.state = {
        name: '',
    }
}

validate() {
   if(_.size(this.state.name) < 3) {
      ...
      this.fieldOne.current.focus() // this is not working
    }
}

render() {
return(
.... 
<TextInput
    placeholder={'Name'}
    autoCapitalize='words'
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoFocus={false}
    keyboardType='default'
    value={this.state.name}
    ref={this.fieldOne}
    selectionColor={colors.PRIMARY_LIGHT}
    placeholderTextColor={colors.PRIMARY_LIGHT}
    underlineColorAndroid={colors.NO_COLOR}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ name: text })}
/>
 ...
}
```

In validade method I'd like to focus the cursor within the field when it isn't right. I've looked on the internet and also I posted this problem as an issue at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20817. Although, I haven't found a real solution yet.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` your `validate` function, or use an arrow function.

You can either add the following to the bottom of your `constructor`

```
this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
```

Or, change your function to an arrow function

```
validate = () => {
  // Function body
}
```

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.io/r1G1ESTUm), clicking on the button will focus on the `TextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dan! I appreciate your answer, especially the example! However, it hasn't worked for me. Anyway, I've installed the react-native-elements and I've been using that stuff.